# How I can get the selected option on element upon change in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following select and using Jquery I manage to get the new value so I can process it further:

```js
 $("select[name=time]").on('change',function(e){
    const target = event.target;
    console.log(target);
    console.log($(target).val());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="time" class="container-full">
       <option value="12:00" data-payvalue=2300>12:30</option>
       <option value="13:00" data-payvalue=2301>13:00</option>
       <option value="14:00" data-payvalue=2101>14:00</option>
    </select>
```

But what I want is to also retrieve the `data-payvalue` of he selected options as well. Do you know how I can do it?

In order words I want to do:

```js
     $("select[name=time]").on('change',function(e){
        const target = event.target;
        console.log(target);
        console.log($(target).val());
        const payvalue=''; //populate with selected option having data-payvalue
        console.log(payvalue)
     });
```

What I want to do is once I select in the example the value `13:00` to display:

```
  console.log(payvalue)
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to call the custom attribute like this:

```
const payvalue = $('option:selected').attr("data-payvalue"))
```

Comment: It works as long as value is unique inside the option. If there are 2 `option` nodes with same `value` attribute it may not work.

Comment: understood, I edited it , you didn't mention that

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is:

```js
 $("select[name=time]").on('change',function(e){
    const target = event.target;
    console.log(target);
    console.log($(target).val());

    //populate with selected option having data-payvalue
    const payvalue=$(target).find(":selected").attr('data-payvalue'); 
    console.log(payvalue)
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="time" class="container-full">
       <option value="12:00" data-payvalue=2300>12:30</option>
       <option value="13:00" data-payvalue=2301>13:00</option>
       <option value="14:00" data-payvalue=2101>14:00</option>
    </select>
```

Pay attention upon:

```
        //populate with selected option having data-payvalue
        const payvalue=$(target).find(":selected").attr('data-payvalue'); 
        console.log(payvalue)
```